# Numpy.tostring and back to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to convert a numpy array to a string representation of the array and then back to the array itself. below is the data from using
`frame_string = numpy.array2string(frame, separator=',')` When I try to convert it back to a numpy array with `numpy.fromstring(frame_string, dtype=int, sep=',')` I end up with an empty `[]`
What am I doing wrong? been banging my head against a wall with this issue for a while now.
Any help is appreciated!

```
"""[[[24,25,22],
  [24,24,21],
  [24,24,21],
  ...,
  [36,24,30],
  [36,24,30],
  [35,23,29]],

 [[26,26,24],
  [25,25,23],
  [26,24,23],
  ...,
  [37,25,31],
  [37,25,31],
  [37,25,31]],

 [[28,25,25],
  [29,26,26],
  [30,27,27],
  ...,
  [38,26,32],
  [39,27,33],
  [39,27,33]],

 ...,

 [[22,23,18],
  [22,23,18],
  [24,22,18],
  ...,
  [21,20,24],
  [21,20,24],
  [20,19,23]],

 [[22,23,17],
  [23,23,17],
  [25,22,18],
  ...,
  [21,20,24],
  [21,19,25],
  [20,18,24]],

 [[23,23,17],
  [24,23,17],
  [26,22,18],
  ...,
  [21,20,24],
  [21,19,25],
  [20,18,24]]]"""
```

Comment: Rereading the `fromstring` docs might have saved you some head-banging.  OK, it doesn't explicitly say what it can't handle.  But the examples like `''1, 2"` are pretty simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.fromstring` is not the inverse of `numpy.array2string`. NumPy does not provide any inverse of `numpy.array2string`.

In fact, it is **impossible** to recover your original array from the string shown. By default, `numpy.array2string` will summarize large arrays, replacing large chunks of their content with `...`. We can see that this happened with your array. That data is lost. The [documented](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions) way to avoid this would have been to pass `threshold=sys.maxsize` to the `array2string` call.